# What does <! mean in SHTML?

Tags: shtml

I am modifying some SHTML files and have run across the following

```
<! IMG height=1 src="x.gif" width=1 border=0>
```

I have never seen the `<!` without the `--#` following it to denote a server side include.

Is this valid SHTML? If so, what does it do.

I tried searching, but you can imagine how frustrating it gets to do a search on `<!` ... LOL

Comment: apparently, I can't even type it.. <!

Comment: <! IMG height=1 src="x.gif" width=1 border=0>

Comment: user1799058, use backticks to mark things as code, they won't be interpreted as markup then. Fixed it for you...